# How do I remove the color swatch from my HighCharts legend without affecting the column?

Tags: jquery, highcharts

In my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NDpu6/34/) the swatch by `My Company` is blue. I already know that I can replace the swatch with a symbol as shown in the JSFiddle posted, but how would I go about removing the other swatch without affecting the columns and just keeping the series name `My Company`. I tried setting the color to transparent removes the swatch but also makes the column transparent and setting the legend to false removes the legend.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there may be a cleaner solution to this, however I've found a solution that works right now.

you have the option to style the legend 'symbols' and setting the height to 0px effectively hides it.

I've added 

`legend: { symbolHeight: '0px' },`

you can read more about the API options here: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend

and here is your revised demo.

http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/NDpu6/35/